# Spring boot application into Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Spring boot application which is configured with https with the below properties.

```
server.ssl.keyStore=/users/admin/certs/appcert.jks
server.ssl.keyStorePassword=certpwd
server.ssl.trustStore=/users/admin/certs/trustcert
server.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustpwd
```

These applications were running in VM's and the certs were placed in the defined path. Now, trying to deploy this application into Kubernetes and not sure how to achieve this.

I already have created mount for application.properties in configMap. 
In my dockerFile,

> --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties

and in deployments.yaml like the below one.

```
"spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "app-prop",
        "configMap": {
          "name": "app-config",
          "items": [
            {
              "key": "application.properties",
              "path": "application.properties"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "app-service",
        "image": "docker.com/app-service",
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "app-prop",
            "mountPath": "/conf"
          }
        ],
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      }
    ],
```

The property server.ssl.keyStore is in application.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those keystores are password protected, arguably you could just bundle them into the docker image and reference them relative to the image's root, then inject the passwords via enviroment variables that are set from `Secret`s:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: spring-ssl
data:
  keyPass: bAsE64TxT
---
kind: Pod
# etc
containers:
- env:
  - name: SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        key: spring-ssl
        name: keyPass
```

Spring Boot will grab those correctly formatted environment variables and apply them on top of any other configuration values, yielding (hopefully) the correct assignment without having to hard-code the passwords anywhere easily accessible

However, if you'd prefer to keep even the jks out of the docker image, then one could feel free to stash the jks in the same `Secret`, or even a separate one, and `volumeMount` the jks in place

Comment: Great, but traditionally `ConfigMap` and friends are for values that you wouldn't want protected by RBAC roles, whereas `Secret`s are values you really would only want a small number of `ClusterRole`s to be able to read -- but yes, there's nothing _technically_ stopping you from putting everything in a `ConfigMap`

Comment: I guess, the above example can be used for jks also after stashing the jks in Secret. Why do we still need to volumeMount? Any example pls ...

Comment: _Why do we still need to volumeMount_ as I mentioned, I actually wouldn't bother with volume mounting the jks, since it is already password protected; I would just stash them in the docker image. At work, we put all the config yamls in the docker image, and then inject only the secrets, or overridden values, via the environment

Comment: Got it. So, I dont need the mount option if i add the jks file into Secrets data and can use as mentioned above.

Comment: _I dont need the mount option if i add the jks file into Secrets_, no that's the 100% opposite of what I said

Comment: I meant,

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: jks-cert
data:
  cert: <WHOLE_CERT_HERE>
---
kind: Pod
# etc
containers:
- env:
  - name: SERVER_SSL_KEY_STORE
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        key: jks-cert
        name: cert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167784/discussion-between-user1578872-and-matthew-l-daniel).